# Downloading a site through ftp

Tags: ftp

I need to download a large set of files of a cpp library from a site. I was thinking about using ftp, but i'm not to familiar with ftp. This is the site. https://svn.code.sf.net/p/cppunit/code/branches/HB_VS2010/cppunit/

Comment: Not sure about using ftp, but you can use wget with --recursive (can't remember the exact option name) which will grab everything under that link and wget will follow the link and grab everything below them as well

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'm running windows so I can't use wget. Does anybody have a better answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use wget on windows :)

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

And if you want exact copy of what is online on your PC, you can use -mirror:

```
‘--mirror’
Turn on options suitable for mirroring. This option turns on recursion and time-stamping, sets infinite recursion depth and keeps ftp directory listings. It is currently equivalent to ‘-r -N -l inf --no-remove-listing’.
```

Answer (score 0):

The site uses an svn repository, ftp may be possible but it would be easier to use either the svn tool or alternatively you may use.

http://downloadsvn.codeplex.com/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Error accepted!